# gtk 2.7 package for python on windows

Tags: python, windows, gtk

How to install gtk 2.7 package gobject for python on windows 7?

I'm getting this error:

```
ImportError: No module named gtk
```

Comment: How are you importing it? Shouldn't that be `from gi.repository import Gtk` (which would give a different error)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume you mean Gtk for Python 2.7. Gtk 2.7 is ancient. You would want to use pygobject:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pygobjectwin32/

And then:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
```